# How to use OCR in Windows 10 apps (UWP)?

Tags: c#, ocr, windows-10, uwp

How do you use OCR in UWP?
In previous windows 8.1 apps the OcrEngine initialization was like this:

```
OcrEngine ocrEngine = new OcrEngine(OcrLanguage.English);
```

but when in UWP it doesn't work. So how do you use OCR in windows 10 apps?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can find [OcrEngine](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.media.ocr.ocrengine.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1) class in `Windows.Media.Ocr` namespace, use `TryCreateFromLanguage` method to create a new `OcrEngine` instance.

```
Language ocrLanguage = new Language("en");
OcrEngine ocrEngine = OcrEngine.TryCreateFromLanguage(ocrLanguage);
```